# Bind Spring MVC Interceptor to URL with Java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What is the Java config alternative to Spring MVC XML namespace's `<mvc:interceptor>` tag:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
       <mvc:mapping path="/some/specific/path"/>
       <ref bean="XX" />
    <mvc:interceptor>
<mvc:interceptors>
```

I know about overriding the `addInterceptors()` method of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` but  I'm particularly interested in mapping my interceptors to certain URLs (or controllers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure an interceptors and map them to URLs by Java configuration.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(new DetailInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/activities/{activityId}");
            registry.addInterceptor(new CollectionInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/activities");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Is there also an approach similar to ControllerLinkBuilder's linkTo(Class) in Spring's HATEOAS API? I.e. adding the URL pattern based on a controller's URL mapping.

Comment: As you said you can user ControllerLinkBuilder and to get a URL pattern this way:
linkTo(methodOn(ActivityController.class).getActivity(null)).toString()

But in the configuration it throws NullPointerException... I guess that a configuration is loading before controller beans. It is an another problem to solve.

Comment: Maybe it is getting old. It is almost 3 years old solution.

Comment: There's no need for the @EnableWebMvc annotation.